# SED, GREP, AWK, regex do not display content between two patterns until match the end of second pattern

Tags: regex, awk, sed, grep

Example:

```
demo, demo-setga, Deployment (apps) has changed:
...
-           image: "imagedemo43"
+           image: "imagedemo44"
...
demo, demo-app1, Deployment (apps) has been removed:
- # Source: /charts/app1/templates/deploy.yaml
- apiVersion: apps/v1
-       imagePullSecrets:
-         - name: demo-registry
+
demo, demo-app2, Deployment (apps) has changed:
...
-               value: 4.2.0
+               value: 4.3.0
...
demo, demo-app4, Deployment (apps) has been added:
-
+ apiVersion: apps/v1
+ kind: Deployment
+ metadata:
+     heritage: Helm
+       imagePullSecrets:
+         - name: demo-registry
demo, demo-app9, Deployment (apps) has changed:
...
-               value: 2.2.0
+               value: 4.3.0
...
demo, demo-app5, PodDisruptionBudget (policy) has been added:
-
+ apiVersion: policy/v1beta1
+ kind: PodDisruptionBudget
+ metadata:
+       app: app5
+       release: demo
../helm_var/test/dev/secrets.yaml.dec
demo, demo-app8, PodDisruptionBudget (policy) has been added:
-
+ # Source: test/charts/app5/templates/pdb.yaml
+ apiVersion: policy/v1beta1
+     matchLabels:
+       app: app5
+       release: demo
demo, demo-app9, Deployment (apps) has changed:
...
-               value: 4.1.0
+               value: 9.3.0
...
```

Desired Output:

```
demo, demo-setga, Deployment (apps) has changed:
...
-           image: "imagedemo43"
+           image: "imagedemo44"
...
demo, demo-app1, Deployment (apps) has been removed:
- # Source: /charts/app1/templates/deploy.yaml
- apiVersion: apps/v1
-       imagePullSecrets:
-         - name: demo-registry
+
demo, demo-app2, Deployment (apps) has changed:
...
-               value: 4.2.0
+               value: 4.3.0
...
demo, demo-app9, Deployment (apps) has changed:
...
-               value: 2.2.0
+               value: 4.3.0
...
../helm_var/test/dev/secrets.yaml.dec
demo, demo-app9, Deployment (apps) has changed:
...
-               value: 4.1.0
+               value: 9.3.0
...
```

start the pattern with line: `added:`

end pattern: `+` not all,  just until they stop on the same block.

block example:

```
demo, demo-app4, Deployment (apps) has been added:
-
+ apiVersion: apps/v1
+ kind: Deployment
+ metadata:
+     heritage: Helm
+       imagePullSecrets:
+         - name: demo-registry
```

I tried this  `sed  '/added:/,/\+,\n/d' file`, output not desired:

```
demo, demo-setga, Deployment (apps) has changed:
...
-           image: "imagedemo43991"
+           image: "imagedemo44236"
...
demo, demo-app1, Deployment (apps) has been removed:
- # Source: /charts/app1/templates/deploy.yaml
- apiVersion: apps/v1
-       imagePullSecrets:
-         - name: demo-registry
+
demo, demo-app2, Deployment (apps) has changed:
...
-               value: 4.2.0
+               value: 4.3.0
...
```

I tried this  `sed  '/added:/,/\+/d' file`, output not desired:

```
demo, demo-setga, Deployment (apps) has changed:
...
-           image: "imagedemo43991"
+           image: "imagedemo44236"
...
demo, demo-app1, Deployment (apps) has been removed:
- # Source: /charts/app1/templates/deploy.yaml
- apiVersion: apps/v1
-       imagePullSecrets:
-         - name: demo-registry
+
demo, demo-app2, Deployment (apps) has changed:
...
-               value: 4.2.0
+               value: 4.3.0
...
+ kind: Deployment
+ metadata:
+     heritage: Helm
+       imagePullSecrets:
+         - name: demo-docker-registry
demo, demo-app9, Deployment (apps) has changed:
...
-               value: 4.2.0
+               value: 4.3.0
...
+ kind: PodDisruptionBudget
+ metadata:
+       app: app5
+       release: demo
../helm_var/test/dev/secrets.yaml.dec
+ apiVersion: policy/v1beta1
+     matchLabels:
+       app: app5
+       release: demo
demo, demo-app9, Deployment (apps) has changed:
...
-               value: 4.2.0
+               value: 4.3.0
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk '/^[^+-]/{f=(/added:/)} !f' file
demo, demo-setga, Deployment (apps) has changed:
...
-           image: "imagedemo43"
+           image: "imagedemo44"
...
demo, demo-app1, Deployment (apps) has been removed:
- # Source: /charts/app1/templates/deploy.yaml
- apiVersion: apps/v1
-       imagePullSecrets:
-         - name: demo-registry
+
demo, demo-app2, Deployment (apps) has changed:
...
-               value: 4.2.0
+               value: 4.3.0
...
demo, demo-app9, Deployment (apps) has changed:
...
-               value: 2.2.0
+               value: 4.3.0
...
../helm_var/test/dev/secrets.yaml.dec
demo, demo-app9, Deployment (apps) has changed:
...
-               value: 4.1.0
+               value: 9.3.0
...
```

Comment: That is a cool awk my man...

Answer (score 0):

This Perl does what you describe:

```
perl -0777 -pE 's/^.*added:[\s\S]*?(?=^[^+-])//mg' file
```

Prints:

```
demo, demo-setga, Deployment (apps) has changed:
...
-           image: "imagedemo43"
+           image: "imagedemo44"
...
demo, demo-app1, Deployment (apps) has been removed:
- # Source: /charts/app1/templates/deploy.yaml
- apiVersion: apps/v1
-       imagePullSecrets:
-         - name: demo-registry
+
demo, demo-app2, Deployment (apps) has changed:
...
-               value: 4.2.0
+               value: 4.3.0
...
demo, demo-app9, Deployment (apps) has changed:
...
-               value: 2.2.0
+               value: 4.3.0
...
../helm_var/test/dev/secrets.yaml.dec
demo, demo-app9, Deployment (apps) has changed:
...
-               value: 4.1.0
+               value: 9.3.0
...
```

Based on [THIS](https://regex101.com/r/U2nN29/1/) regex.

OR, this awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{f=1} 
     /added:$/{f=0; next}
     f==0 && /^[^-+]/ {f=1}
     f
' file 
# same output...
```

Or, if you really need 1 less line:

```
awk '/added:$/{f=1; next}
     f==1 && /^[^-+]/ {f=0}
     !f
' file
# same...
```